# SQLite + Hibernate

Tags: java, sqlite, hibernate, intellij-idea

Не получается задать относительный путь. После создания артефакта (IDEA) при открытии сессии выводит ошибку: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement

Я пробовал сделать как здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36207826/hibernate-h2-database-relative-path

Пробовал как здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19807320/hibernate-sqlite-db-outside-jar

Я иногда встречаю вот такую формулировку Assuming that your classpath is now established. Мне нужно что сделать... в манифесте в classpath указать бд? Но тогда я не понимаю как это сделать.

### hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
        org.sqlite.JDBC
    </property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:sqlite:./testfx_db
    </property>

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
    </property>

    <property name="show_sql">
        true
    </property>

</session-factory>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как-то же идее удаётся найти файл базы, если он лежит в корне проекта. То есть, из среды разработки выполняется всё отлично. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что когда вы запускаете проект из JAR - вся файловая система в терминах загрузки лежит вся внутри JAR, грубо говоря загрузчик классов ничего не знает о внешнем мире. Соответственно:

1) Или вы указываете в манифесте где у вас еще есть файлы `Class-Path: db/`

2) Или вы включаете в свой JAR БД, далее при первом запуске копируете БД во внешний мир и вручную соединяете с hibernate с БД.

Comment: Я добавляю Class-Path: lib/ db/
А ни папка бд ни создаётся, ни когда я в jar захожу открываю манифест файла бд там не указано.
А папка либ создаётся вне jar файла...https://ibb.co/jGW4sGG

Comment: `db/` - в этот каталог (вне JAR) надо положить либо вручную либо программно вашу БД. JAR автоматически ее не создаст.

Comment: то есть, я в идее создаю папочку lib и запихиваю туда все нужные jar'ки и идея генерирует эту папку, а если я создаю папку db то идея её игнорирует. Так от чего это зависит? Папка с именем db игнорируется или потому что там не содержится jar'ки? По сути, какая разница что там находится и как какая папка называется, я написал что ресурс находится в такой-то папке, почему она не создаётся? А если я хочу не создавать базу, если у меня, например, программа для тестирования школьников и все вопросы должны браться из уже существующей базы. И как файл .deb будет работать?